# Shuffle columns of an array with Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have an array `r` of dimension `(n, m)`. I would like to shuffle the columns of that array.

If I use `numpy.random.shuffle(r)` it shuffles the lines. How can I only shuffle the columns? So that the first column become the second one and the third the first, etc, randomly.

**Example:**

input:

```
array([[  1,  20, 100],
       [  2,  31, 401],
       [  8,  11, 108]])
```

output:

```
array([[  20, 1, 100],
       [  31, 2, 401],
       [  11,  8, 108]])
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One approach is to shuffle the transposed array:

```
 np.random.shuffle(np.transpose(r))
```

Another approach (see YXD's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20546567/1787973) is to generate a list of permutations to retrieve the columns in that order:

```
 r = r[:, np.random.permutation(r.shape[1])]
```

Performance-wise, the second approach is faster.

Comment: It is. I recommend `r.T` for transpose, though.

Comment: @user2357112 is `r.T` the exact same thing as `np.transpose(r)` but shorter?

Comment: Effectively identical. There's a very slight difference for 1-d arrays, but you probably won't be using either `T` or `transpose` for 1-d arrays.

Comment: I don't think that's what you're looking for, though. The transposition of a matrix is like making the columns into rows, and the rows into columns. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html What you were asking about was swapping col1 for col2, yes?

Comment: Since numpy.shuffle shuffles the rows, but taking the transpose of a mtrix, you effectively shuffle the columns. Then you transpose back.

Comment: I take that back. It's almost what you want. Transpose the matrix, shuffle the rows, then transpose back.

Comment: @Matt: This is an in-place operation on a view of the original array. It does not create a new, shuffled array, so there's no need to transpose the result.

Comment: @user2357112 Got it. We're not storing the transposition so r is never really transposed in the first place, but the shuffle acts as though it were due to the way the matrix is presented to it. It's not the spoon that bends, as it were. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to have each row shuffled independently?

Comment: Note that this operation shuffles every row along the columns the same way. Like in your example,  the first element is swapped with the second while the third remains the same for every row. If this is what you want that's great but I would be curious for a solution that shuffles the columns for every row independently.

Comment: isn't your last edit copying this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66757740/6451573

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre and without even crediting it... I thought that new and different approaches deserve different posts/answers; otherwise we are accumulating everything into a single accepted answer

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I know that people will blindly copy my answer because it has more votes, that's why I've decided to add the other alternative. I've added the missing credit to YXD. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 6):

For a general axis you could follow the pattern:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> a = np.array([[  1,  20, 100, 4],
...               [  2,  31, 401, 5],
...               [  8,  11, 108, 6]])
>>> 
>>> print a[:, np.random.permutation(a.shape[1])]
[[  4   1  20 100]
 [  5   2  31 401]
 [  6   8  11 108]]
>>> 
>>> print a[np.random.permutation(a.shape[0]), :]
[[  1  20 100   4]
 [  2  31 401   5]
 [  8  11 108   6]]
>>>
```

Comment: Something is wrong with the code, shuffling the columns should not return the original matrix in general.

Answer (score 5):

So, one step further from your answer:

Edit: I very easily could be mistaken how this is working, so I'm inserting my understanding of the state of the matrix at each step.

```py
r == 1 2 3
     4 5 6
     6 7 8

r = np.transpose(r)  

r == 1 4 6
     2 5 7
     3 6 8           # Columns are now rows

np.random.shuffle(r)

r == 2 5 7
     3 6 8 
     1 4 6           # Columns-as-rows are shuffled

r = np.transpose(r)  

r == 2 3 1
     5 6 4
     7 8 6           # Columns are columns again, shuffled.
```

which would then be back in the proper shape, with the columns rearranged.

The transpose of the transpose of a matrix == that matrix, or, [A^T]^T == A. So, you'd need to do a second transpose after the shuffle (because a transpose is not a shuffle) in order for it to be in its proper shape again.

Edit: The OP's answer skips storing the transpositions and instead lets the shuffle operate on r as if it were.

Comment: `np.random.shuffle` does not return the array.

Comment: So I see, edited. Regardless, the final step is needed to return your matrix to its original shape.

Comment: @Matt: No, no it's not. `transpose` returns a view of the original array. Once you shuffle the transposed array, the original is shuffled in the desired manner. There is no need to transpose twice.

Comment: @user2357112 I added a sample matrix to each step to illustrate my thought pattern. It's been a decade since my last linear class, but I'm pretty sure this is what the documentation for np.tranpose and np.random.shuffle indicate is going on.

Comment: @user2357112 read your comment to the question, got it now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In general if you want to shuffle a numpy array along axis `i`:

```
def shuffle(x, axis = 0):
    n_axis = len(x.shape)
    t = np.arange(n_axis)
    t[0] = axis
    t[axis] = 0
    xt = np.transpose(x.copy(), t)
    np.random.shuffle(xt)
    shuffled_x = np.transpose(xt, t)
    return shuffled_x

shuffle(array, axis=i)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> print(s0)
>>> [[0. 1. 0. 1.]
     [0. 1. 0. 0.]
     [0. 1. 0. 1.]
     [0. 0. 0. 1.]]
>>> print(np.random.permutation(s0.T).T)
>>> [[1. 0. 1. 0.]
     [0. 0. 1. 0.]
     [1. 0. 1. 0.]
     [1. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

np.random.permutation(), does the row permutation.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way, which does not use transposition and is apparently **faster**:

```
np.take(r, np.random.permutation(r.shape[1]), axis=1, out=r)
```

CPU times: user 1.14 ms, sys: 1.03 ms, total: 2.17 ms. Wall time: 3.89 ms

The approach in other answers:  `np.random.shuffle(r.T)`

CPU times: user 2.24 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 2.24 ms
Wall time: 5.08 ms

I used `r = np.arange(64*1000).reshape(64, 1000)` as an input.

Comment: That's a very interesting approach! I recommend you to use `timeit` to prove that it's really faster. And according to my tests, it seems to be the case!

Comment: `r[:, np.random.permutation(r.shape[1])]` seems to be even faster than using `np.take`

Comment: @MaximeChéramy I used `%%time` because `timeit` was caching the intermediate results and it wasn't clear what was happening. `r = r[:, np.random.permutation(r.shape[1])]` is nice! But I have the impression that `np.take` with `out=r` uses less memory. Can you use `%memit` to check?

Comment: Based on my timing experiments, in fact `r[:, np.random.permutation(r.shape[1])]` does not appear to be faster than `np.take`. Most likely the speed-up that you see is because of caching.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.random.Generator.shuffle` has an `axis` parameter. This will shuffle in place:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
rng.shuffle(arr, axis=1)
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.shuffle.html